# Google App Script: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getConnection on object Jdbc

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script, jdbc

I am trying to connect a Google App Script to a SQL Express SQL Server on my local PC. I believe I have the port 1433 opened on my firewall (for what that is worth) and have my SQL Server enabled, TCP/IP enabled, etc... My google App Script code is:

```
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databasename=MY_DATABASE",'GOD','GOD');
```

This is returning the error: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getConnection on object Jdbc.

I see other posts from years ago that say "google is aware and working on fixing the problem" and I see those tickets as closed. So, I'm not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to google ip 127.0.0.1 You would get `The IP address 127.0. 0.1 is a special-purpose IPv4 address and is called the localhost or loopback address. All computers use this address as their own, but it doesn't let computers communicate with other devices as a real IP address does.` That was the first item on my search.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into my issue. I am using 127.0.0.1 specifically because I want to connect my App Script to the SQL Server database my own PC. So, I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Yes but Googlle Apps Scripts don't run on your computer.  They run on Google Server so  I believe it is exactly the problem because google servers probably use the very same address for their loop back.